# Sum of decimal numbers gets wrong answer RDLC Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, report, rdlc

I am trying to sum decimal amounts. For example i have 10.5 and 20.5 but sum of these are 310.00 it is wrong..

My code :

`=IFF(Fields!CURRENCY.Value = "USD" , FormatNumber(Sum(CDbl(Iff(Fields!AMOUNT.Value = "","0", Fields!AMOUNT.Value))),2),0)`

Comment: seems like the decimal separators are ignored - what's your locale, and what's the separator for it? try `10,5`, for example.

Comment: I tried but problem still persists.